# Removing Null rows from a UNION Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

How do I remove null rows from a union query and sort the results ASC. The below query returns the correct unsorted data but it also includes a null row.
How do I accomplish this task? Also I would appreciate if someone can advise on a more efficient method. Thanks you SO.

```
SELECT TOP 1 'All rooms' AS [SELECTION:] FROM tbl1 UNION ALL 
(SELECT DISTINCT Room1 FROM tbl1 WHERE Room1 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT Room2 FROM tbl1 WHERE Room2 IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT Room3 FROM tbl1 WHERE Room3 IS NOT NULL);
```

Current output:

```
All rooms
Common Room
201
20
20.1
    'Null row here
256
```

Expected:

```
All rooms
20
20.1
201
256
Common Room
```

Comment: @TimWilliams I just tagged MS Access. thx

Comment: Looks like you have zero length strings in there, which are not the same as null. Either change your table def to disallow zero length strings or compare to '' (empty string).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the second line - you are selecting room1 `where room2 is not null`, perhaps you mean either `where room1 is not null` or `where room2 is not null and room1 is not null`

```
SELECT TOP 1 'All rooms' AS [SELECTION:] FROM tbl1 UNION ALL 
(SELECT DISTINCT Room1 FROM tbl1 WHERE Room1 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT Room2 FROM tbl1 WHERE Room2 IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT Room3 FROM tbl1 WHERE Room3 IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Kenny that is corrected and the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get solution to this problem by using `Len` function instead of the `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 'All rooms' AS [SELECTION:] FROM tbl1 
UNION ALL( SELECT DISTINCT Room1 As [SELECT LOCATION:] 
FROM tbl1 WHERE Len(Room1) >=1 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT Room2 FROM tbl1 
WHERE Len(Room2)>=1 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT Room3 
FROM tbl1 WHERE Len(Room3)>= 1
ORDER BY [SELECTION:]);
```